# Show that the pointwise limit of $f_n$'s is increasing. By increasing we mean that $f(x) \le f(y)$ if $x \le y$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> Let $f_n$ be a sequence of increasing functions from $[0,1] \to \Bbb R$. Show that the pointwise limit of $f_n$'s is increasing. By increasing we mean that $f(x) \le f(y)$ if $x \le y$.

Suppose that $f_n$ converges to some $f$ pointwise. I want to show that this $f$ is indeed increasing.

By pointwise convergence we have that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $n_0 \in \Bbb N$ such that $$|f_n(x) -f(x)| < \varepsilon.$$

We thus have that $f_n(x) - \varepsilon < f(x)  < \varepsilon + f_n(x)$. Now if $x \le y$, then $$f(x) -f(y) < \varepsilon +f_n(x) - f(y) \le \varepsilon + f_n(y) - f(y) < 2 \varepsilon.$$

Now when $\varepsilon \to 0$ we have that $f(x) -f(y) \le 0 \iff f(x) \le f(y)$ so $f$ is also increasing. Is this a correct argument? I saw that this should be done by contradiction, but I don't know whether this works also.

Comment: It is perfectly valid to just take limits on both sides of the inequality $f_n(x) \leq f_n(y)$.

Comment: Given $\epsilon$ the $n_0$ you introduced may depends on $x$ since you asked pointwise convergence. You can fix that by taking $n_0$ which is fine for both $x$ and $y$ (that are fixed). Except that detail your proof is fine, although as said in the above comment I think it's more natural to pass to the limit into inequalities.

Comment: blamethelag is correct. You chose $n_0$ based on the convergence at $x$ and just assumed it also held at $y$. It could be a much higher $n_0$ is needed at $y$. However, since there are only two arguments involved, you can pick the higher value of $n_0$ and get something that works for both. So only a minor tweak is needed in your proof. Also, just because something *can* be proven by contradiction doesn't mean it has to be.